# NullPointerException when trying to draw image

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to draw an image in my frame but I keep getting a NullPointerException. Here is what I have so far

```
package windows;
import BreezyGUI.*;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Title extends GBFrame{
    static Graphics g ;
    private BufferedImage bg;
    public Title(){
        bg = null;
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/TitleImage.png").toURI().toURL());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

but it always ends up printing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at windows.Title.<init>(Title.java:22)
```

The image i need, TitleImage.png, is inside the folder "images" in the source folder "resources".

Any help for a beginner is appreciated.

Comment: "what is a null pointer" dupe inc I can bet :p

Comment: g isn't assigned. It is null

Comment: g is null and then you attempt to call drawImage, but g is null and therefore you get your null pointer exception

Comment: g isn't assigned at all, let alone null - there's other code in the superclass GBFrame or else this doesn't compile. Which line is line 22? If I copy the text verbatim, I get a lone } as line 22

Comment: @antonyh a variable is null when it is not assigned a value or assigned a null value - they are one and the same.

Comment: Heh. I wonder which language I'm thinking of... thanks for educating me :-)

Comment: Actually, I'm half right - if it's a declaration in a method, it does throw a compilation error like `Error:(7, 26) java: variable xyz might not have been initialized` - but if it's a static like in this question it assigns it to null.

Answer (score 0):

your "g" isn't assigned. So when you try to call a method on it, it shows a NullPointerException. Hope it solves your problem ;) 
(another beginner)

Comment: Figured it out... Thank you!